# How to route all traffic through VPN via router?

Tags: security, vpn

How can I configure my NETGEAR Nighthawk AC1900/R7000 to send all traffic (except games, if possible) through Private Internet Access?

PIA supports IPSec, L2TP and OpenVPN and my router is currently running NETGEAR Genie V1.0.4.30_1.1.67.

I couldn't find any options related to the above VPN protocols in the settings (shown below):

[image]

Comment: That interface is for setting up a VPN server on your router (e.g. so you can connect from the outside back to your home network), not configuring your router to be a VPN client . . .

Comment: Oh. Well, that explains that. Does Genie not have what I need then? Should I install Tomato?